# How to change JComboBox items to Integers

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

How to change JComboBox items to Integers

I Tried to to convert the String that i have get it from the JComboBox to Int like this but there is an Exception

```
int hrCBvalue = (Integer) hrCB.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(hrCBvalue);
```

This is how i make the JComboBox and it is not editable, How can i edit it?

```
hrCB.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should parse the string to integer

```
String hrCBvalStr = hrCB.getSelectedItem();
int hrCBval = Integer.parseInt(hrCBvalStr);
```

Regarding the non editable JComboBox part, is there any chance you might have set the `setEnabled()` method to false? The snippet you have posted should work fine by itself.